# SVG image clip from text only working in IE11, other browsers yielding various results

Tags: html, css, svg, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

Hi so I made best effort to make several different keyword searches for my problem and I couldn't seem to find any previous posting so i'm posting this. If I missed one that is similar please excuse me and direct me to it.

So I'm using SVG on an img to clip text as my title for my little home-project website. It yields exactly the desired result in Internet Explorer 11 on windows. Problem is, it yields very different results on other browsers, as such:

```
WIN - IE 11            = "Dal's Domain" <- desired result
WIN - Edge v38         = "Dal's D"
WIN - Firefox (newest) = "Dal's D"
WIN - Chrome v58       = "Dal's D"
MAC - Chrome v49       = "[blank]"
```

This is my website as it stands: [DStealth.com](http://dstealth.com)

For quick reference:

HTML

```
<div id="title-wrapper">
  <svg id="image-svg">
    <image id="title-img" height="530" width="530" href="z_index/pics/clouds.jpg" alt="Dal's Domain" />
  </svg>
</div>

<svg id="svg-defs">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip-text">
            <text x="0" y="58" textLength="530px" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" font-family="Bank Gothic" font-size="72px" font-weight="500" font-style="normal">Dal's Domain</text>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

CSS

```
#title-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 530px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #FBFCFE;
    border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: 2px solid #6685B7;
}
#image-svg { left: 0px; top: 0px; }
#title-img { clip-path: url(#clip-text); -webkit-clip-path:url(#clip-text); }
#svg-defs { 
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Please help me figure out why it's not working in other browsers and how I can get it to do so.

Comment: Try adding width attribute to <svg> element.

Comment: yes that did it!! but my friend with the mac is offline so I have no way to check if that one got fixed too. Did you want to post it as an answer so I may give you a checkmark?

Comment: great! I just added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding width attribute to  element.

Comment: This fixed the problem on WIN-Chrome v58/Firefox/Edge but my friend just tested it on his MAC-Chrome v49 and the div is appears blank with no text. Could this be because he has an outdated version? Or is it MAC related?

Comment: How about using viewBox? see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox and http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html`